# Get π in python scripted expression for a driver?

Tags: python, drivers

Get **π** in python scripted expression for a driver?

Comment: pi or radians(180)

Comment: @SixthOfFour thanks... I tried math.pi, after nearly a year of javascript & php, I just couldn't believe it was as simple as pi! :D P.S. Post that as an answer

Comment: I think math is already imported by default, and mapped so you needn't specify it. I'm still learning Python though, so I'm not sure how it's done. However, I use XYZ math surface quite a lot, and it has both `pi` and `radians()` without having to specify the math module.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`pi` or `radians(180)` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I didn't know about the backticks. I'll try to remember them. :)

Comment: What import should be done to reference it in a script? In console `pi` is recognized, just as `bpy` is, in a script however, I notice that `import bpy` has to be done.